# Cannot delete processes in opsworks recipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, sidekiq

I wrote own custom recipe:

```
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|
  Chef::Log.info("test")
  release_path = ::File.join(deploy[:deploy_to], 'current')

  execute "start" do
    cwd release_path
    command "pkill -f sidekiq; bundle exec sidekiq -C config/myschool_sidekiq.yml -d -L log/sidekiq.log"
    environment "RAILS_ENV" => 'staging'
  end
end
```

And deploy is failed.

If I run code without

```
pkill -f sidekiq;
```

than deploy is success but old sidekiq process remained.

In logs I didn't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions

```
command "kill -9 `cat tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid`; bundle exec sidekiq -C config/myschool_sidekiq.yml -d -L log/sidekiq.log -P tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid"
```